# url rewriting or chage urls for wordpress website links

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i've the following website built in wordpress
http://www.drwagenberg.com/ the previous developer has created four template pages
and creates all the things in posts with different categories.here is one of template page code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: detail
*/
?><?php get_header(); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/banner.php'); ?>
<div id="inner_servce_bx">   <!-- inner service bx -->

<?php $cat_id=$_GET['catid']; ?> 
<div id="inner_heading">
<?php  $title = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$cat_id"); 
    foreach ($title as $objt)  {
    $main_title =  $objt->name; ?>
  <div id="inner_hdng_txt"><?php echo $main_title; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
  </div> 

  <div id="servcs_smal_bx">  <!-- service service bx -->

<?php  $service_id = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE parent=7 order by term_id asc"); 
foreach ($service_id as $obj)  {
$service_cat_id =  $obj->term_id; ?>
<?php  $service_name = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE term_id=$service_cat_id"); 
foreach ($service_name as $obj1)  {
$service_cat_name =  $obj1->name;
$service_cat_id = $obj1->term_id; ?>

        <div id="servcs_smal_bx1">  <!-- servcs smal bx1 -->
        <div id="servc_title_bx">  <!-- servc title bx -->
          <div id="title_txt"><?php echo $service_cat_name; ?><br/>
<span id="title_txt1"><?php echo category_description( $service_cat_id ); ?></span></div>
<!-- servc title bx end -->
        <?php query_posts("cat=$service_cat_id&meta_key=short_desc" );  ?>      
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>            
<div id="servc_sml_img"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short_img', true); ?></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- servc title bx end -->
<?php query_posts("cat=$service_cat_id&meta_key=short_desc" );  ?>      
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="serv_descrip"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'short_desc', true); ?></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="read_mre1"><a href="index.php/?page_id=53&catid=<?php echo $service_cat_id; ?>">Read More...</a></div>
        <div id="ser_btm_line"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/srvice_line.jpg" width="439" height="42" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php } } ?>

    </div>

</div> <!-- service service bx end -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

then on each template page check for the category called and load that category from database on that template page. so the urls looks like this

```
http://www.drwagenberg.com/?page_id=101&catid=8
```

the permalinks are set to this type

```
post   http://www.drwagenberg.com/sample-post/
```

is there any easy way that the url's shown in the address bar are set to my desired type like

```
http://www.drwagenberg.com/services-procedures/periodontal-disease
```

and how i'll do this for SEO Optimization???

Comment: make use of custom structure option in the permalinks menu under settings in the wp-admin

Comment: @ManigandanArjunan the custom can not work on permalinks when you defined the template page and load different post on their category base. as shown in code. if possible share link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Permalinks

Change it to the format you want there, using the Custom Structure option. Copy and paste the below code into there and it will change across your website:

```
%category%/%postname%/
```

Comment: tried this but the permalinks aur not changed, as you can see on the link http://www.drwagenberg.com/ Only category shown can be acceptable tooo

Comment: Firstly, it looks like your nav links are hard coded to the type you've mentioned, so clicking on them won't help. You will need to change them yourself manually.

From the backend, get a category url key, (ie services-procedures if it exists) and a post url key from within that category, and try it in your address bar with the above permalinks selected. That should definitely work.

Comment: provide example to change link for this menu item
    '<li><a href="/?page_id=51&catid=7"><?php echo $menu_cat_name; ?></a></li>' Thanks